# How to programmatically execute a test suite using JUnit4?

Tags: junit, automated-tests, junit4, test-suite

I am trying to invoke a JUnit Test suite using the API. I know that you can suite up test classes using the following:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
  Test1.class,
  Test2.class, ...
})
```

But, is there a way to trigger the entire suite using the Java API, using JUnitCore for example?

For example, you can trigger a test by using the following code:

```
Runner r = 
try {
  r = new BlockJUnit4ClassRunner(Class.forName(testClass));
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | InitializationError e) {
  // handle
}
JUnitCore c = new JUnitCore();
c.run(Request.runner(r));
```

**Update:**

From the API, it seems that the Suite class itself is a runner, hence the following code seems to work:

```
Suite suite = new Suite(klass, new RunnerBuilder() {
... // Implement methods
});
JUnitCore c = new JUnitCore();
c.run(Request.runner(suite));
```

But I am not sure if this is a recommended approach or if there is any downside to writing the above code.

Answer (score 14):

Just specify the name of the suite class to JUnitCore:

```
Computer computer = new Computer();

JUnitCore jUnitCore = new JUnitCore();
jUnitCore.run(computer, MySuite.class);
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew! I will definitely give this a try. In the meantime, do you have recommendations for the code snippet in my update?

Answer (score 4):

You can also that using command prompt as

**java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore test class name**

Comment: I don't think that this qualifies as "programmatically".

Comment: It will if you call it using runtime.exec