# Is it possible to execute test cases sequentially in Android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, kotlin, instrumentation

I have written multiple test cases in an Android project but I want to execute test cases one after another. That means sequential execution need to occur.

> When the first test case is complete then another test case will be
>   executed
>   For example if we have two screens Login and Home Page then after the successful test case of the Login it should execute test case for Home Page

I am a beginner for the Unit testing. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127052/how-to-programmatically-execute-a-test-suite-using-junit4) but not working.

How this will be possible? Here is my code:

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, ListFragment()).commitAllowingStateLoss()
    }
}
```

Test Case for Main screen

**MainActivityTest**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MainActivityTest {

    @get: Rule
    var signInActivityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)

    private var signInActivity: MainActivity? = null

    @Test
    fun testEventFragment() {
        signInActivity = signInActivityTestRule.activity
        val container = signInActivity!!.findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.container)
        Assert.assertNotNull(container)

        val fragment: Fragment = ListFragment()
        signInActivity!!.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(container.id, fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss()

        getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync()
        val jUnitCore = JUnitCore()
        val computer = Computer()
        jUnitCore.run(computer, ListFragmentTest::class.java)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate more on how it is not working

Comment: @Andreas Question  was updated please check it -> jUnitCore.run is not working to run another test case

Comment: That still does not explain how it is not working. Does it have syntax error? Does it give any error message? Does it just skip the test? Also what is the implementation for ListFragmentTest?

Comment: @Andreas I Don't get any kind of error it will just skip the next test case